# Kivy program with GIF has a completely white screen

Tags: android, python, kivy

I wanted to make an small Kivy program with a GIF. It worked perfectly on my PC,
but when I compiled it, pushed it to my device and ran it, all I got is a white screen.

Here is my code:

```
class Contrail(Image):
    frame_counter = 0
    frame_number = 6 # my example GIF had 6 frames
    def on_texture(self, instance, value):     
        if self.frame_counter == self.frame_number + 1:
            self._coreimage.anim_reset(False)
        self.frame_counter += 1


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Contrail(source = "streifen1.gif")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need to include `gif` in bulldozer.spec file.  Here: `source.include_exts = py, png, ... , gif`